# Configuring CORS at WSO2 microintegrator with Integrator Studio

Tags: angular, wso2, cors, wso2-micro-integrator

I have setup some API for angular consumption, but I get CORS issues from prefligth options.
I set up an API for OPTIONS and an API for POST.

Reading here and there, I got this:

```
<property description="Request-Headers" name="Access-Control-Request-Headers" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="*"/>
<property description="Allow-Methods" name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="OPTIONS POST"/>
<property description="Allow-Headers" name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="*"/>
<property description="Allow-Origin" name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="*"/>
<property description="application-json" name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
<property description="RESPONSE" name="RESPONSE" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
```

The request get property logged to a log mediator to the option api, but when I test the api, my configuration isn't set:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: 
Access-Control-Request-Headers: *
Host: localhost:8290
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 10 Nov 2020 01:17:25 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{ 
    "status":  "ok"
}
```

**Specifically Allow-Methods is my principal concern**

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The easiest way I found, was to leverage cors authentication to nginx, and use nginx as loadbalancer infront of wso2...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WSO2 EI V7.x.x or V8.x.x, just add the following configuration to the `<EI_HOME>/runtime/microesb/conf/deployment.toml` file:

```
[synapse_properties]
'synapse.rest.CORSConfig.enabled' = "true"
'synapse.rest.CORSConfig.Access-Control-Allow-Origin' = "http://127.0.0.1:5500, http://localhost:5500"
'synapse.rest.CORSConfig.Access-Control-Allow-Methods' = "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS"
'synapse.rest.CORSConfig.Access-Control-Allow-Headers' = "content-type, Accept, Authorization"
```

Change the allowed origin, methods, and headers according to your need.

For WSO2 EI v6.x.x, check out [the docs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Enabling+CORS+for+Data+Services+).

Also, try to specify your frontend base URL in the allowed origin header instead of "*".